# How to map object and get distinct values from array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Based on an array of `Setting`, I want to map the items, stripping the key and value and then only get distinct items based on that key.

```js
class Setting {
  settingKey!: string;
  value!: string;

  //Multiple other properties in here...
}
```

I'm using the same class to hold the groups, but I could also use a `Tuple`, `Pair` or other class.

```js
settings: Setting[] = [];
settingsGroups: Setting[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {

 this.settings = [
  { settingKey: "GroupName1.SettingsName1", value: "100" },
  { settingKey: "GroupName1.SettingsName2", value: "200" },
  { settingKey: "GroupName2.SettingsName1", value: "300" },
 ]

 this.settingsGroups = this.settings.map(element => {
     var key = element.settingKey.slice(0, element.settingKey.indexOf('.'));
     var value = element.settingKey.slice(element.settingKey.indexOf('.'));

     return new Setting({ settingsKey: key, value: value });
 });
}
```

My issues are that I'm not able to instantiate a Setting object and I don't know how to filter the result just to get the two groups.

---

Edit, I was able to instantiate and filter the array. I just could not create a one liner for the instantiation.

```
  this.settingsGroups = this.settings.map(element => {
    var key = element.settingKey.slice(0, element.settingKey.indexOf('.'));
    var value = element.settingKey.slice(element.settingKey.indexOf('.'));

    var setting = new Setting();
    setting.settingKey = key;
    setting.value = value;

    return setting;
  }).filter((element, i, arr) => arr.findIndex(t => t.settingKey === element.settingKey) === i);
```

Comment: Can you write out exactly what you expect the contents of `this.settingsGroups` to be at the end?  Like, imagine you were hardcoding it instead of trying to process `this.settings`; what would its contents be?

Comment: I solved that, I just wanted to group by group name and my only issue rioght now is if it's possible to create and instance of a class and populate its values in one liner, like C#.

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] the question and remove all references to the part you’re not asking about (especially the title)  There’s undoubtedly a more targeted [mre] for initializing class instances.